# How to find and replace text with sed but with special characters

Tags: bash, sed

I am writing some bash script from wchich I need to replace some text in another file
I need to find and replace the following text in myfile

```
$conf['extra_login_security'] = true;
```

with:

```
$conf['extra_login_security'] = false;
```

so I tried the following:

```
sed -i 's_extra_login_security'] = true_extra_login_security'] = false_g' myfile.php
```

but it did not work I am getting the following error:

```
sed: -e expression # 1, character 15: unknown option for the `s' command
```

can you help me and tell what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed "s/\(extra_login_security'] = \)true/\1false/" myfile.php
```

*Details*:

- `\(extra_login_security'] = \)` - Capturing group 1: `extra_login_security'] =`  string
- `true` - a fixed string
- `\1false` - replacement: Group 1 value + `false` substring.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/AuF1Q5):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s="\$conf['extra_login_security'] = true;"
sed "s/\(extra_login_security'] = \)true/\1false/" <<< "$s"
# => $conf['extra_login_security'] = false;
```